# "No usable default provider could be found for your system" with VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

When trying to init a Vagrant box with VirtualBox, I keep getting this error:

> No usable default provider could be found for your system.
>
> Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
>   "providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
>   environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.
>
> The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
>   is available for free on all major platforms.
>
> If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it is
>   properly installed and configured. You can see more details about why
>   a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with `vagrant up
>   --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific error message for that particular provider.

After some searching it seems that Vagrant has compability issues with particular versions of VirtualBox. I'm running Vagrant 2.0 together with VirtualBox 5.2 on MacOS High Sierra. Is this simply not possible, or is there a workaround?

Update: It is a compatibility issue between Vagrant and VirtualBox – tried installing VirtualBox 5.1.14 instead and it works with Vagrant 2.0.

Comment: What is the exact command you try to run when you try to `vagrant init`

Comment: I'm confused :) Using https://box.scotch.io (popular dev box), they state I should only run vagrant up after cloning the repo. If I try vagrant init it in the same directory I'm told I need to remove the Vagrant file before continuing.

Comment: Did you `cd my-project` and run `vagrant up` in that directory? I just followed the steps on the website you linked and it works for me!

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Could it be something with my installation? I'll try and reinstall VirtualBox. Are you using the same version of VB?

Comment: It's possible, a co-worker had to update his VirtualBox in order to set vagrant up properly. My VB version is Version 5.1.24 r117012 (Qt5.6.2).

Comment: Ok, will install an older version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it with VirtualBox 5.2 with this patch:
https://gist.github.com/roktas/ec34960d2e5d74c3cc4f35bc78bc676d

Comment: This solution worked for me great! Vagrant version 2.0.0 and VirtualBox 5.2